# Class Library vs (Portable) vs (Universal Windows) vs (Portable iOS, Android, Windows)

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, win-universal-app, portable-class-library

I'm having trouble understanding the difference between all these different Class Library templates in Visual Studio 2015. Can anyone explain or provide documentation? I've tried looking but have been unsuccessful.

[image]

Comment: Just now I'm looking for it. @JustinSkiles If you found an answer, mind answering your question?

Comment: @JoaoMilasch Sorry, I never found the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Portable's can run and be referenced without having to be installed
Class libraries are the standard libraries to windows desktop apps
Universal (which I have never used) I believe to be specific to Win8, Win10 and Windows Store apps across many devices

I am fallible as anyone else so don't take it as 100% fact on the Universal libs, but that is my understanding